# Trying to display JSON data, but JSON Parse Error

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display JSON data on my screen, the integer 4 to be exact.

But, I am receiving a JSON Parse Error.

I've posted and that works fine as in Webhooksite says it successfully posted. Also, it "gets" fine, but the data doesn't display.

```
// JSON Data

{
    "cheetosamount": 4,
    "cookiesvalue": 2
}
```

```
export default class ChooseDeliveries extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.handleGetRequest();
  }

  handleGetRequest() {
    fetch ('https://webhook.site/e61dd236-92d5-4b3b-882b-a50d6add6cd3',{
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: responseJson,
        isLoading: false,
      })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  };


  render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    } else {
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
          <Text>
            {this.state.dataSource.cheetosamount}
          </Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  } 
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you expect dataSource to be an array or an object? Looks like the default value is set to an empty array, but you are then trying to turn it into an object with setState. Try changing the default value to an empty object. Or conversely, put responseJson in an array before trying to update the state

Answer (score 0):

The code seems ok having a glimpse at it maybe try and wrap the response with a JSON.parse?? That would be

```js
...
this.setState({
  dataSource: JSON.parse(responseJson),   <-- HERE
  isLoading: false,
})
...
```

Comment: I have added the parse function, but I am still receiving the same JSON Parse error...